# In C++, can you do lambda capture by reference on a rvalue?

Tags: c++

if I have defined in c++:

`using CustomFunc = std::function<void(std::string input)>;`

Now I a given lambda that captures CustomFunc by right value, and that lambda contains an inner lambda that calls the CustomFunc passed in from outer lambda:

```
//....
functionBThatTakesInALambda([](CustomFunc&& func){
   std::string input = GeneratesRandomString();
   myObj->functionBThatTakesInALambda([func](input){ func(input); });
});

//....
```

Assuming the first `CustomFunc&& func` is intentional and cannot be changed, should the send `func` in the inner function be capture by value as is, or `&func` instead ? (ie, can you capture by reference on an rvalue?)

Is there a better way to do the above? (assuming the outer and inner lambda structure must be preserved).

Comment: Depends on the lifetime of the target object? But since it's an rvalue reference, presumably the target dies soon after, so you should capture by value (but better do `func = std::move(func)` to avoid a copy).

Comment: ok, i still need to capture `func` in the inner lambda by value, and when i do that, doesn't it copy it again (capture by value means copy), which will undo the std::move in the outer lambda ?

Comment: @user1008636 HolyBlackCat means to capture via move (C++14 feature):  `[func=std::move(func)](input)` ...

Comment: got it, but doesn the initial ```CustomFunc&& func``` in the outer lambda already means `func` is a rvalue, and i can move an rvalue?

Comment: Read up on `std::forward`. Nope, it's an lvalue. Every variable is. Doesn't matter that it's called "rvalue reference" and can be initialized with rvalues.